# How settings it is for Amazon S3 to make public automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to use an URL Object. When i upload an image from Node.js server to Amazon S3, I want to automatically access an URL Object. And you can detail step by step what I need to do to work? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but your question is difficult to understand. Are you saying that you want to upload an image to an Amazon S3 bucket and you would like that image to be publicly accessible to _anyone_ on the Internet? Would you want the _whole_ bucket to be public, or just the image that you upload?

Comment: Well, when I upload a picture from the server, the URL is automatically set to public, I don't care if it's still public or just the image I'm uploading. I need to have immediate access to the url of the image without giving it to "Make public" and to put it automatically on the public

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options for making your upload public:

#### Option 1: Use ACL

When uploading the image, use `ACL=public-read`.

This will make the object publicly accessible.

You will also need to **turn off S3 Block Public Access** for the two options that mention ACLs.

#### Option 2: Use a Bucket Policy

If you wish to make the *entire bucket* public, you can add a Bucket Policy:

From [Bucket policy examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html):

```json
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Before adding this Bucket Policy, you will need to **turn off S3 Block Public Access** for the two options that mention Bucket Politices.

Comment: Well, in option 2, I also need putObject, because I'm loading from a Node.js server. or I don't have to put putObject to load from the Node.js server

Comment: i try option 2 and i got a error:  https://ibb.co/C8R0gRT

Comment: It is _not_ an IAM Policy. It is a **Bucket Policy** that needs to go on the Amazon S3 bucket (in the _Permissions_ tab of the bucket).